# Disable Sortable option

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, rubaxa-sortable

How can I disable sorting using the javascript from https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable temporarily?

[see this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Hs92U/). that's how it's set up:

```
$('ul').each(function( index ) {new Sortable(this, { group: "sortgroup" });
             });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dev version](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/tree/dev), which will be released in December 2014, introduces a `sort: <Boolean>` option. Setting it to `false` disables the ability to sort the list. This is useful if you want to have a "source" list, from which you can drag elements into a "destination" list, but don't want to sort elements in the source list.

Check out the demo - http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/#ag

Standalone non-sortable list demo: http://jsbin.com/sevofa/1/edit?html,js,output

```js
var sortable = new Sortable(document.getElementsByClassName('sortable')[0], {
      group: 'foo',
      sort: false,
      animation: 150
});

switcher.onchange = function () {
  var on = switcher.sort.value == 1;
  sortable.option('sort', on);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RubaXa/Sortable/dev/Sortable.js"></script>

<form id="switcher">
  sort: 
  <label><input checked name="sort" value="0" type="radio"/> false</label>  
  <label><input name="sort" value="1" type="radio"/> true</label>
</form>

<ul class="list-group sortable">
  <li class="list-group-item">This is <a href="http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/">Sortable</a></li>
  <li class="list-group-item">It works with Bootstrap...</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">...out of the box.</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">It has support for touch devices.</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Just drag some elements around.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to give the constructor **handle**-parameter.

```
$('ul').each(function( index ) {
    new Sortable(this, { group: "sortgroup", handle: ".someClass"});
});
```

Sort happends when user clicks element containing that class. [Instructions here](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable#options).

Comment: this is working, but i need to set a class to every li element in each ul which could be many elements. Isn't there a better way to disable the sorting altogether like remove it from document?

Comment: Can you do a simple jQuery for that? $('li').addClass('someClass'); Before you create that Sortable-object

Comment: If you want to remove something from DOM for later usage, you can use jQuery's [**detatch**-method](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)

Comment: detatch won't work as i don't want to remove any elements from the dom at all

Comment: Then you can just add that class to specified elements via jQuery. Now that I think about it, you can do that also after creating that Sortable object as well. Could that be the answer?

Comment: maybe the jQuery is the best solution for now? .. although a simple function like disableSortable would be nice that just uses the parent element (UL).

Comment: I think jQuery is the simplest solution for now. Disabling sort should really be provided by that library itself.

Comment: [Sortable now has the option of disabling sort](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27242272/1269037).